# Can't edit cells in DataGridView with Dataset with foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, dataset

**I can't edit any of the cells in the view except for the combobox; none of the textboxes are editable** (when I click, it doesn't begin editing, just shows that it's selected).

I've created a form using the designer, added a DataGridView, and created a DataSet from two database tables; Detail and Master. Detail contains a foreign key relationship to Master.

I then bound the DataGridView to Detail and changed the columns as needed. I added a combobox column that uses Master as its data source, Type (property of master) as Display member, Master ID as its Value Member, and Detail ID as its DataPropertyName; this was in order to show the foreign key relationship.

I then went through all of the properties of the table, the form, the columns, and the cells and made sure that **read-only is set to false**. I also checked through the code of the dataset and couldn't find any properties that could be causing this.

I've tried handling the cell-click event and that isn't working either.

---

I've discovered that the issue is caused by the following code. The goal is to add a new row to the grid for each entry in the master dataset that doesn't already have an entry in the detail dataset if the master is marked as required. I'm calling this method in the load method, right after fill is called.

**How can I add these rows without breaking the existing ones?**

```
    private void AddRequiredRows()
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in tWODataSet.VendCertMaster.Rows)
        {
            if (((VendCertMasterRow)row).Required)
            {
                DataRow[] foundDetail = tWODataSet.VendCertDetail.Select("ID 
                = " + ((VendCertMasterRow)row).ID + " and VendorID = '" + 
                VENDORID + "'");
                if (foundDetail.Length == 0)
                {
                    vendorGridView.Rows.Add(row["Type"], "", "", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a clean project to see if the problem is reproducible.

Comment: I'll do that right now, thanks! I'll comment afterward.

Comment: I found the issue; I've updated the question.